# What is the conditional probability if we condition with the empty set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It's an interesting question I think (or what is most likely I'm missing some subtle details). On one hand, we know that the empty set is independent of any other event so for any $A \in \mathcal{F}:$ $P( A \, | \, \emptyset) = P(A)$, on the other hand, if we write this conditional probability using the definition, we might get that something is divided by zero. So what is $P( A \, | \, \emptyset) :
 \\
P(A)\,, \, 0 \, \,\text{or something undefined ?}$

p.s.: I added zero because intuitively if we know that everything is wrong (our condition) then A must be wrong (like never to happen).

Comment: The probability is not defined in such case.

Comment: How can you elaborate that?

Comment: Well, by definition, the conditional probability of A given B would be the probability of their intersection / conjunction divided by the probability of B. If B is the empty set you get null probability (the empty set has no measure) and thus would yield division by 0. Thus, undefined.

Comment: You can't really ever condition on the empty set. You can condition on a set of probability zero sort of, in the case of continuous random variables, but that isn't proper conditional probability and is really a different construction.

Comment: You can condition on an event of probability 0 by taking a limit, but the result can depend on how you "approach" the null event. This is [Borel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox).

Comment: $0/0.$.........

Answer (score 1):

I know it is way too late, but just for other people checking this post: The conditional probability is only defined when the event that has already occurred (B) has a probability greater than zero.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).